# How to extract the bottleneck layer from the below architecture?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

**I have created an model (down below). And after training, I want to get the output tensor from the bottleneck layers of this model.**
So I am trying to create a model of the extracted layers and use this model for predicting.

```
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation

nstrides = (1,1)
inputs = layers.Input(imshape)

conv01 = layers.Conv2D(32, 4, activation = 'relu', 
                       strides = nstrides, padding="same")(inputs)
conv1 = layers.Conv2D(32, 4, activation = 'relu', 
                       strides = nstrides, padding="same")(conv01)
pool1 = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)

.
.


#block4
conv04 = layers.Conv2D(256, 4, activation = 'relu', 
                       strides = nstrides, padding="same")(pool3)
conv4 = layers.Conv2D(256, 4, activation = 'relu', 
                       strides = nstrides, padding="same")(conv04)
pool4 = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv4)

#bottlneck
conv05 = layers.Conv2D(512, 4, activation = 'relu', 
                       strides = nstrides, padding="same")(pool4)
conv5 = layers.Conv2D(512, 4, activation = 'relu', 
                       strides = nstrides, padding="same")(conv05)
upconv5 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(256, kernel_size=(2, 2), 
                       strides = (2,2))(conv5)

#upblock 1
conc6 = layers.concatenate([upconv5, conv4])
conv06 = layers.Conv2D(256, 4, activation = 'relu', 
                       strides = nstrides, padding="same")(conc6)
conv6 = layers.Conv2D(256, 4, activation = 'relu', 
                       strides = nstrides, padding="same")(conv06)
up7 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(126, kernel_size=(2, 2), 
 strides = (2,2))(conv7)
.
.
.

#combine the model together
model = Model(inputs, outputs)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, in order to locate the desired layer which would be the new output tensor, you can first do

```
for i, layer in enumerate(model.layers):
    print(i, layer.name)
...
...
12 max_pooling2d_15
13 conv2d_65
14 conv2d_66
15 conv2d_transpose_12
16 concatenate_12
17 conv2d_67
...
...
```

Here, the layer index from **13** to **15** is from the bottleneck layer of your model. If you want to get the output tensor from this bottleneck layer, you can do:

```
new_model = Model(model.input, 
                model.get_layer(index=15).output)
# or, 
new_model = Model(model.input,
                model.get_layer(name='conv2d_transpose_12').output)
```

Both are the same, the first one is by **index** and the second one is by layer **name**.